# Android app to run terminal commands

Tags: c#, android, android-studio, mono, terminal-emulator

Okay so i use terminal a lot on android basically to run a C# program using mono. Now i was wondering if it was possible to make an android app which could run the terminal mono code for me in one click.

What i want,
To open the app and it automatically executes the terminal command say `apt-get update` every time I open the app and nothing else. 
Basically I want to make an android app that could run terminal commands. 
So is it possible to run terminal commands via an android application. If yes then how?